# Rewriting a URL address with port to a subdomain

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I've a few applications running at different ports. In Apache or nginx (or other common solution), how do you rewrite this:

http://stackoverflow.com:8085 to the following: http://new.stackoverflow.com

And also:

http://stackoverflow.com:8085/api/feed to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/sys/api/feed

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. As http standard always defaults to port 80. To use any other port you would have to specify the port in the URL like you have done so